# Any quick way to export all images in a pre-saved html file at once?

Tags: images, export, html-files

My situation is that I have a html file I saved that has 100+ images that I want to export all at once..
Please excuse me if that is a dumb question, I am not a computer geek in any way..

Comment: Here is the contents of the accompanied folder   https://ibb.co/D4mVYXW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save a web page in browsers like Chrome, Firefox, etc..., it will make a new folder with the same name as your html file with the suffix `_files`. So if your html file is named `my_page.html`, then the folder will be named `my_page_files`.
That folder will contain all of the data from the page, such as images, sounds, css files, etc... .

Comment: Yes.. but mine is an exception.. I used Image Max URL , a script which which replaced thumbnail images with the large ones ..I will post a screenshot of the files in the folder